# How to convert an int pointer to the reference of an int array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, types, casting

I just come across the following problem:

```
void func( int (&arr)[3] ){...}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int* a = new int[3];
    a[0]=0, a[1]=1, a[2]=2;
    f(a);// how to convert a int* to int(&)[3]?

    delete[] a;

    return 0;
}
```

My point is how could I convert the pointer "a" to the required int array?

Comment: This reeks of undefined behaviour. Why would you not just use a normal array?

Comment: use delete [] a ( for new []) .....

Comment: `func( *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3]>(a) );` but I'm not sure if it's legal.

Comment: @jrok, You meant to put a reference, and I don't think it would be guaranteed to work, but it seems fairly reasonable it would. I'd rather not rely on it.

Comment: No, the pointer is intended, notice I dereference it.

Comment: @jrok, Oh, I missed that tiny little star.

Comment: This post here also has some good info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046429/casting-pointer-to-array-int-to-int2