# Casting pointer to Array (int* to int[2]) - Casting and assigning to an array from a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Learning pointers can be tricky. Accessing them like arrays is pretty straight forward and easy to understand. Creating them can be tricky to understand because of the multiple ways `&` can be used. Casting them to anything seems to be really easy to do, and a way to break all sorts of things if not done carefully.

Two things I wasn't taught about was casting pointers to arrays and assignment of arrays. Pointers cast to basically any type, so presumably it should be an easy task to cast to an array type. As for assigning to arrays, this presumably will be possible since everything else is assignable unless const.

So something like the following would be so elegant for casting a pointer to an array type and assigning to an array.

```
int x = 1
int arr[2] = { 2, 3 };
int* ptr   = new int[10];
// plus some initialization code for ptr
arr = &ptr[1]; // assign address of ptr[1] to arr
```

This didn't work, so before wasting anyone's time I wanted to make sure I understood the data I was working with. Values, and addresses primarily. So, I made a simple program to output some of the addresses and values. The output is just below:

```
Address of {type: int}    &x      =       0031FEF4; x    = 1
Address of {type: int[2]} &arr    =       0031FEE4; arr    = 0031FEE4
Address of {type: int[2]} &arr[0] =       0031FEE4; arr[0] = 2
Address of {type: int[2]} &arr[1] =       0031FEE8; arr[1] = 3
Address of {type: int*}   &ptr    =       0031FED8; ptr    = 008428C8
Address of {type: int*}   &ptr[0] =       008428C8; ptr[0] = 2
Address of {type: int*}   &ptr[2] =       008428D0; ptr[2] = 1
```

After making it clear to myself that I "knew" what values were where such as the address stored at `arr` I came here to figure out why `arr = &ptr[1];` did not work.

Shouldn't `arr` be assignable? Can I not cast a pointer to an array in such a way?

Comment: First, why would you need that ? Hint: `int*` and `int [2]` have different purposes (though the second one can decay into the first).

Comment: I am trying to simplify a file reading function. This is the concept I am grappling with in order to do said simplification.

Comment: Things never get simpler with pointers-to-arrays. Just use plain pointers and sizes.

Comment: @rodrigo Things never get simpler with arrays. Just use `std::vector`

Comment: @Caleth Indeed! That was exactly my conclusion in my answer below ;-).

Comment: `memcpy` could be used, yet nasty :(

Comment: I often wish I could do this in the debugger, not so much in production code where it's generally not a good practice.  For example, if I have an array of float that happens to be represented in the code as a float pointer, it would be nice to expand the array.

Comment: @JBL "First, why would you need that ? Hint: int* and int [2] have different purposes". Exactly! So what if array decaying is not your purpose? It's forced on you inside a function and many times you'd want to treat it as an array like f.i. `std::begin(arr)`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First of all `b` is an array, not a pointer, so it is not assignable.

Also, you cannot cast anything to an array type. You can, however, cast to pointer-to-array.
Note that in C and C++ pointer-to-arrays are rather uncommon. It is almost always better to use plain pointers, or pointer-to-pointers and avoid pointer-to-arrays.

Anyway, what you ask can be done, more or less:

```
int (*c)[2] = (int(*)[2])new int[2];
```

But a `typedef` will make it easier:

```
typedef int ai[2];
ai *c = (ai*)new int[2];
```

And to be safe, the delete should be done using the original type:

```
delete [](int*)c;
```

Which is nice if you do it just for fun. For real life, it is usually better to use `std::vector`.

Comment: So this is the only way to take a memory address and make it the start of an array? By changing the way I define said array; turning it into a pointer to an array and then casting to that?

Comment: Actually the C way is to use the pointer as-is: remember that you can subscript a pointer just fine. The cast to pointer-to-array is mostly useless, except maybe in multi-dimension arrays. I mean, you can think of a `int*` as pointing to a single integer, or as pointing to the first of an array of integers.

Comment: This undefined behavior in C++. `int*` and `int(*)[2]` are two different pointer types. You are essentially doing an illegal `reinterpret_case` from one type to another and violating the _strict aliasing rule_.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod No time to look it up in the standard, but I believe that an aggregate type and the type of its first element are *not unrelated* and that pointers to each can be cast between.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider § 6.9.2(4) of the C++17 standard: "An array object and its
first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address."

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: That note in the standard says that those pointers are not _pointer-interconvertible_, but does not say what _pointer-interconvertible_ means. From other pieces of the standard, I'm guessing that _pointer-interconvertible_ just means that the pointer address may be changed by `static_cast<>`. See in particular the last para of `static_cast`: "[if the type is not pointer-interconvertible then] then the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion"; that suggests that if the types are pointer-interconvertible, then the pointer type may be changed by the conversion.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod How can I violate the aliasing rule if I access an int through an int pointer? *Of course* I can do that, we do it all the time! We have **two distinct questions** here: **1.** Does the pointer have the correct numerical value? (Note that I could validly e.g. cast a literal integer value for hardware access!) The answer is an undisputed yes. **2.** Does the resulting expression have the object's type (here: int)? The answer is yes. The aliasing rule is for something else: It forbids accessing this object through pointers of dissimilar types, like floats.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: he @ from my previous comment was for Thomas, not for Peter, sorry.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, in C++ and `int` and `array of int` are not similar types for the purposes of pointer aliasing. You may be thinking of how a array of int can contextually "decay" into a pointer to int by way of implicit conversion. However, this is different than accessing the first element (or any element) of an array through a **pointer to array of int**. The compiler is entitled to make assumptions about pointers to types and attempting to access an element of an array through a pointer to entire array violates one of these assumptions.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Actually casting the `int *` to an `int(*)[]` is indeed an aliasing violation (and your original remark is correct) because there never was an array object -- funny as that seems since we usually allocate array "substitutes" --, but the reverse cast would be OK, provided the address is indeed the location of an array. I had that latter cast in mind.

Comment: Is it possible to use this trick somehow to pass T* to function that takes T[] ? E.g. in third party library I have the following: MMatrix( const float m[4][4] ); and I want to pass float* to this constructor (technically I have std::array<float, 16> ). Is it possible?

Comment: @DmitriiMotorygin: I don't think so: if a function takes a `std::array<float, 16>` you cannot just pass a pointer, you need to pass _by copy_ the whole 16 values.

Answer (score 2):

Though you can't reassign an array identifier.. sometimes the spirit of what you're doing allows you to simply create a reference and masquerade yourself as an array. **Note:** this is just a slight extension of rodrigo's answer... and it is still worth mentioning that there is probably a better way to accomplish whatever the task is.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x[1000] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int (&sub_x)[100] = *(int(*)[100])(&x[i*100]);
        //going right to left basically:
        // 1. x[i*100] -- we take an element of x
        // 2. &x[N] -- we take the address of the element
        // 3. (int(*)[100]) -- we cast it to a pointer to int[100]
        // 4. *(...) -- lastly we dereference the pointer to get an lvalue
        // 5. int (&sub_x)[100] -- we create the reference `sub_x` of type int[100]
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
            sub_x[j] = (i*100)+j;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        if(i != 0) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << x[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

As you'd expect the output just ends up printing 0-999 with no gaps

output:

```
0, 1, 2, ..., 999
```